# Don't change the state in my component - React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change the state the a child component but don't change, this is the parent component:

```
export default class History extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         histories : JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(histories)),
         counter: 1,
         id: ''
      }
   }

   increaseCounter = () => {
      this.setState({counter: this.state.counter+1})
   }

   showIdHistory = (id) => {
      this.setState(() => {return {id:id}})
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <div className="history">
            <div>
               <h3 className='titleHistory'>{searchHistoryById(this.state.id,this.state.counter)}</h3>
            </div>
            <div className='options'>
               <div className='option'>
                  <BottonOptionA  option='A' increaseCounter={this.increaseCounter} showIdHistory={this.showIdHistory}/>

                  <h2>{searchOptionById('a',this.state.counter+this.state.id)}</h2>
               </div>

               <div className='option'>
                  <BottonOptionB  option='B' increaseCounter={this.increaseCounter} showIdHistory={this.showIdHistory}/>

                  <h2>{searchOptionById('b',this.state.counter+this.state.id)}</h2>
               </div>
            </div>

            <div className='sectionStatics'>
               <SelectionBefore optionAnterior={this.state.id}/>
               <reacordOfOptions option={this.state.id}/>
            </div>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

i want that the parent component pass the state to the component called **SelectionBefore** but when the parent child changes the state, the props of **SelectionBefore** still is the same

this is the component child:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'

export default class SelectionBefore extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            optionBefore : props.optionBefore,
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <p> Seleccion anterior: {this.state.optionBefore}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `this.state.opcionAnterior` in `SelectionBefore`?

Comment: @NickVu i have make a mistake the names of the props, i already edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following changes :

Child component

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'

export default class SelectionBefore extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <p> Seleccion anterior: {this.props.optionAnterior}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I have directly used the props which is passed by parent to the child .
This means that , whenever state of parent changes , your child will rerender and the changes will be shown .

Comment: thankss!!, now my code works